# Выбор паттерна или как сделать

Tags: php

Есть pool worker'ов, в каждом worker'e есть шаги которые надо менять из самих же шагов, я для этого передаю worker в сам шаг по ссылке, но мне такое решение кажется не очень красивым и тяжело поддерживаемым.

```
class WorkerPool
{
  $pool;
  public function addWoker(Worker $worker)
  {
    # code...
  }

  public function deleteWorker(Worker $worker)
  {
    # code...
  }
}

class Worker
{
  $step;
  $value;
  public function setStep(Step $step)
  {
    # code...
  }

  public function changeValue($value)
  {
    $this->value = $value;
  }
}

abstract class Step
{
  $worker;
  function __construct(Worker &$worker)
  {
    $this->worker = $worker;
  }

  abstract public function someJobs();

}

class FirstStep extends Step
{
  public function someJobs()
  {
    # code...
    $step = new SecondStep($this->worker);
    $this->worker->setStep($step)
    # or...
    $step = new OtherStep($this->worker);
    $this->worker->setStep($step)
    $this->worker->changeValue('bla');
  }
}

class SecondStep extends Step
{
  public function someJobs()
  {
    # code...
    $step = new OtherStep($this->worker);
    $this->worker->setStep($step)
    # or...
    $step = new FirstStep($this->worker);
    $this->worker->setStep($step)
  }
}
```

В голову приходит еще `singleton` c pool'ом который непосредственно в шагах будет искать нужный worker и менять ему(worker'у) шаг, но тоже неприятно попахивает, пробежался по паттернам по диагонали, и ничего не увидел может кто, что подскажет?

Comment: может CQRS здесь будет лучше?

Comment: @zhenyab cqrs всегда лучше, только как он относится к вопросу?

Comment: @etki может я не до конца понял, что автору вопроса необходимо сделать, но я предположил, что в данном случае CQRS может подойти. Worker может извещать о выполнении работы или выполнении того или иного шага, другие вокеры могут слушать об изменениях и вступать в дело соотвественно когда того требует тот или иной шаг

Comment: @zhenyab вы об этом [CQRS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS)? Воркерам не надо общаться между собой, в шаге нужно менять какие-то параметры воркеров, а так же при необходимости должна быть возможность заменить сам шаг на другой. Главная необходимость не пробрасывать в шагах родительский воркер для его изменения.

Comment: Тут столько ошибок в коде. abstract public function someJobs(){}
метод не может быть абстрактным по сколько имеет реализацию.Изучите patterns fabric,IoC.Их знание могут вам помочь

Comment: Если вопрос касательно нравится/не нравится решение, то я бы порекомендовал для начала сделать рабочий вариант (хоть какой-нибудь), а уж потом выставить его на обозрение. Пока у вас идея без конкретной реализации, сложно о чём-то судить.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan,  код просто для примераю За IoC спасибо, покурю.

Comment: @DmitriiBelikov, код выше - выжимка из рабочего кода.

Comment: Не стесняйтесь и не жадничайте - выложите побольше, а не выжимки всякие. Глядишь проясниться

Comment: А я до сих пор не понимаю идеи. Очень смахивает на кооперативную многозадачность с воркерами выполняющими работу и scheduler, который обеспечивает переключение между ними.

Comment: @vitidev, использую reactphp/promise

Answer (score 1):

как вам реализация с помощью регистри к примеру мы имеем класс который при выполнение, опишу базовый пример

```
static class WorkerGet 
{
   private $worker = array();

   static public function getWorker($key) 
   {
      if(isset(self::$worker[$key]) {
         return self::$worker[$key];
      }

      self::$worker[$key] = new Worker();
      return self::$worker[$key];
   }

   static public function setWorker($key,Worker $worker) 
   { 
      return self::$worker[$key] = $worker;
   }
}
```

в классе `workere` я бы в seter'ах возвращал бы $this

тогда получаеться что вам даже непредёться писать всякие расшширеные классы а просто делать подобное.

```
$worker = WorkerGet::getWorker('testing')
            ->setStep(1) 
            ->setOtherStep()
            ->setOtherProperties($properties);
```

и далее по коду когда вы будете вызывать метод `WorkerGet::getWorker('testing')` вам будет возвращён всегда один инстанс этого воркера...

registry похож на singelton но singleton применяеться для операций над ресурсами, и не хранит в себе инстанс класса а просто отдаёт однажды полученый ресурс или ещё какие либо данные. Registry в свою очередь ввыполняет роль хранилища.

Comment: От меня минус за пропаганду Singleton (да-да, ваш Registry суть Singleton)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev не читаем ответ? registry Дмитрий registry...

Comment: Увы, ответ я прочитал. Тот факт, что вы не создаете экземпляр Registry внутри Registry (как это было бы в случае с Singleton), не меняет сути. Ваш Registry - это Singleton. А проблема здесь не в **названии** паттерна, а в пропаганде **глобальных переменных** (чем, фактически, и являются Singleton и ваш Registry)

Comment: Ну и "_singleton применяеться для операций над ресурсами, и не хранит в себе инстанс класса а просто отдаёт однажды полученый ресурс_" откровенная ложь, противоречащая классической реализации Singleton из GoF

Comment: Подобное решение я упоминал в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Возращайте результат из someJob() который будет инструкциями для Worker по поводу дальнейших действий

Пример(На Js)

```js
function worker(step, initialData) {

  function executeStep(step, initialData) 
    var result = step(data)

    if(result){
      executeStep(result.nextStep, result.nextData)
    }
  }

  executeStep(step, initialData)
}

function firstStep(data) {
    if(...) {
       return null;
    } else {
       return {
         nextStep: ...,
         nextData: ...
       }
    }
}

worker(firstStep, {})
```

Таким образом вы избавитесь от привязки Step к Worker